# Monitor assignment: double buffer (condition variables and mutex)

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex, condition-variable

Hy everyone, I'm trying to do an assignment for the university but I have some problems with the usage of the condition variables and multi-threads. Every time I run the program there is a deadlock. Here I left the text of the exercise with my (wrong) solution, I hope that someone could help me, thank you.

*****************************************TEXT*****************************************___
Monitor assignment: double buffer
Three concurrent threads, P1, P2, and C, cooperate using a shared buffer.  Thread P1 continuously produces an integer number and transfers it to the buffer, using a method called push_int. Thread P2 continuously produces a pair of integer numbers, and transfers them to the buffer, using a method called push_pair. Thread C continuously fetches a value from the buffer, using a method called fetch. The buffer has two slots, which are initially empty.

The methods are supposed to work as follow:
push_int writes a number in any empty slot in the buffer. If the buffer is full, push_int blocks the calling thread, until there is an empty slot; however, if another thread is waiting to write a pair of numbers to the buffer, using push_pair, then push_int blocks the calling thread until not only there is an empty slot, but also there is no other thread blocked on push_pair;
push_pair writes a pair of numbers in the buffer. If one or more of the buffer slots are full, push_pair blocks the calling thread, until the buffer is completely empty;
fetch returns one of the two numbers present in the buffer (it doesn't matter which one), and marks the corresponding slot as empty; if the buffer is completely empty, fetch returns 0, without blocking the calling thread.
Analyze the problem. Design, implement and test a monitor that offers methods push_int(int), push_pair(int, int) and fetch(). Be sure to avoid deadlock as well as any race condition (in other words, the buffer must function correctly). Moreover, concurrency should be preserved: threads should proceed concurrently whenever possible and not block unnecessarily.

Submit your working source code as one or more .c/.h files, and your project as a single .pdf or .txt document. Alternatively, you can submit everything together as single .zip bundle. Do not submit executable files. The project file should contain your design of the monitor, where you briefly explain the general idea behind your implementation. If you like you can add your considerations about anything you consider relevant and noteworthy.

You can start from the usual template and reuse any parts of code you wish, as long as the design is your own.
__**************************************MY SOLUTION**************************************

```
/*
 ============================================================================
 Name        : monitor-template.c
 Author      : 
 Version     : Dec 24, 2021
 Copyright   : Use as you wish
 Description : Template for the implementation of a monitor and its animation
 ============================================================================
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

// CONSTANTS AND MACROS

#define N_THREADS 3
#define N_SLOTS 2
#define Empty 1     //True  = Empty slot
#define Full 0      //False = FUll slot

#define FOREVER for(;;)

// DEFINITIONS OF NEW DATA TYPES

typedef char thread_name_t[10];

typedef struct {
    pthread_mutex_t m;
    pthread_cond_t cv;
    int BUFFER[N_SLOTS];
    int n_w;
    int slots[N_SLOTS];
} monitor_t;

// GLOBAL VARIABLES

monitor_t mon;

//  MONITOR API
void push_int(monitor_t *mon, int item);
void push_pair(monitor_t *mon, int item1, int item2);
int fetch(monitor_t *mon);
void monitor_init(monitor_t *mon);
void monitor_destroy(monitor_t *mon);

// OTHER FUNCTION DECLARATIONS

void *write_int();
void *write_pair();
void *read_buffer();

double spend_some_time(int);

// IMPLEMENTATION OF MONITOR API

void monitor_init(monitor_t *mon) {
    pthread_mutex_init(&mon -> m, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&mon -> cv, NULL);
    mon -> n_w = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<N_SLOTS; i++){
        mon -> BUFFER[i] = 0;
        mon -> slots[i] = Empty;
    }
}

void monitor_destroy(monitor_t *mon) {
    pthread_cond_destroy(&mon -> cv);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mon -> m);
}

void push_int(monitor_t *mon, int item) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mon -> m);
    mon -> n_w++;

    while((mon -> slots[0] == Full) && (mon -> slots[1] == Full)){
            pthread_cond_wait(&mon -> cv, &mon -> m);
    }

    if(mon -> slots[0] == Empty){
        mon -> BUFFER[0] = item;
        printf("P1 is writing: %d\n", item);
        mon -> slots[0] = Full;
    }
    else{
        mon -> BUFFER[1] = item;
        printf("P1 is writing: %d\n", item);
        mon -> slots[1] = Full;
    }
    mon -> n_w--;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mon -> m);
}

void push_pair(monitor_t *mon, int item1, int item2) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mon -> m);
    mon -> n_w++;

    while((mon -> slots[0] == Full) || (mon -> slots[1] == Full)){
        pthread_cond_wait(&mon -> cv, &mon -> m);
    }

    printf("P2 is writing: %d %d\n", item1, item2);
    mon -> BUFFER[0] = item1;
    mon -> slots[0] = Full;
    mon -> BUFFER[1] = item2;
    mon -> slots[1] = Full;

    mon -> n_w--;

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mon -> m);
}

int fetch(monitor_t *mon) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mon -> m);
    int value;

    if((mon -> slots[0] == Empty) && (mon -> slots[1] == Empty)){
        value = 0;
    }
    else{
            if(mon -> slots[0] == Full){
                    value = mon -> BUFFER[0];
                    mon -> slots[0] = Empty;
                }
            else{
                value = mon -> BUFFER[1];
                mon -> slots[1] = Empty;
            }
            pthread_cond_signal(&mon -> cv);
            //pthread_cond_signal(&mon -> cv);
    }

    return value;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mon -> m);
}

// MAIN FUNCTION
int main(void) {

    pthread_t P1_id, P2_id, C_id;
    thread_name_t P1, P2, C;


    monitor_init(&mon);

    sprintf(P1,"t%d",0);
    pthread_create(&P1_id, NULL, &write_int, NULL);

    sprintf(P2,"t%d",1);
    pthread_create(&P2_id, NULL, &write_pair, NULL);

    sprintf(C,"t%d",2);
    pthread_create(&C_id, NULL, &read_buffer, NULL);


    pthread_join(P1_id, NULL);
    pthread_join(P2_id, NULL);
    pthread_join(C_id, NULL);

    monitor_destroy(&mon);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

// TYPE 1 THREAD LOOP
void *write_int(){
    FOREVER{
        spend_some_time(150);
        int item = 45;
        push_int(&mon, item);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *write_pair(){
    FOREVER{
        spend_some_time(100);
        int item1, item2;
        item1 = 13;
        item2 = 65;
        push_pair(&mon, item1, item2);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *read_buffer(){
    FOREVER{
        spend_some_time(40);
        int value = fetch(&mon);
        if(value == 0){
            printf("Empty buffer\n");
        }
        else{
            printf("Read value: %d\n", value);
        }
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

// AUXILIARY FUNCTIONS
double spend_some_time(int max_steps) {
    double x, sum=0.0, step;
    long i, N_STEPS=rand()%(max_steps*1000000);
    step = 1/(double)N_STEPS;
    for(i=0; i<N_STEPS; i++) {
        x = (i+0.5)*step;
        sum+=4.0/(1.0+x*x);
    }
    return step*sum;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mre], with emphasis on the ***minimal*** part.

Answer (score 0):

In function fetch you are returning from fetch before releasing the lock so even if you signal the condition no other thread will ever get the lock:

```
     return value;
     pthread_mutex_unlock(&mon -> m);
```

I am not sure that you need any locking in fetch assuming writing/reading an int to/from memory is atomic AND in fetch you read the buffer for the value before setting slot to empty AND in push functions you set the slot to full after you push an int.
The exercise says you need to fetch one int no matter what the order is and fetch should not block the calling thread, so it should not wait for any push function to finish to get the lock.
Imagine this scenario without fetch using any locking:

1. push_pair is setting buffer[0]
2. push_pair is setting slot[0] to full
3. fetch is called sees slot[0] and fetches buffer[0]
4. fetch signals and now push_int is awaken but the lock is still with push_pair which causes push_int to wait
5. push_pair is setting buffer[1]
6. push_pair is setting slot[1]
7. push_pair relinquishes the lock
8. push_int now can get the lock and write to buffer[0]

Between steps 1-2 or 5-6 fetch won't get the value because it sees slot[0] or slot[1] Empty.

You can try and consider another scenarios and see if not blocking in fetch is not harmful perhaps i missed something. For example even in step 8 if push_int didn't get the lock and instead push_pair got the lock again it won't write anything because the second half of the previous pair is still in buffer.

Not locking in fetch makes reading the values fast but has the downside of the possibility of returning 0 (empty buffer) from fetch after a push request has issued, but i don't see in the question that a fetch must be ordered in time with push (fetch time after push time).